# Problem with using df.loc (panda, latest version installed) after loading votable

Tags: python, pandas, datatable

I am working with a dataset of around 1.7 million entries. I was able to read my data file as a .csv because I took a small sub-sample of about 1000. Then, easily navigated through analysis by using df.loc to call upon the columns in the file.

Now, I am facing a problem of using df.loc after I tried using the syntax below to read the votable file (yes, not csv because an excel file is unable to load).

PS: I have panda 24.2 , using df = pd.read_table(r'C:\Users\Binaries') is also problematic

```
from astropy.io.votable import parse
def votable_to_pandas(Binaries):
    votable = parse(Binaries)
    table = votable.get_first_table().to_table(use_names_over_ids=True)
    return table.to_pandas()

df = votable_to_pandas(Binaries)

df2 = df.loc[:,"astrometric_chi2_al"]
df3 = df.loc[:,"astrometric_n_good_obs_al"]
```

# ERROR: function has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: First check df is really `DataFrame` and if it is `DataFrame` then check `pandas version. It is very strange.

Comment: Odd indeed. Check that df is working as a dataframe. type(df)

Comment: I am not sure what (df) - run-out will do, since it is not working?